# Microsoft 365 API Authentication

Tags: c#, onedrive, office365api, office365-restapi

I have the following code written. When the user clicks on a hyper link he is redirected to the login page with the Return URL as https://localhost:44300/Office365/Office365Response. I have written the following code to get the Access Token. But I always receive an error as specified below. Where am I going wrong?

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.  We received a bad
>   request. Additional technical information:  Correlation ID:
>   2e875fd4-f5a6-4003-9887-357c4a890e90  Timestamp: 2016-01-19 08:28:20Z 
>   AADSTS90056: This endpoint only accepts POST requests.
>
> Additional technical information:   Correlation ID:
>   2e875fd4-f5a6-4003-9887-357c4a890e90  Timestamp: 2016-01-19 08:28:20Z 
>   AADSTS90056: This endpoint only accepts POST requests.

```
    public ActionResult Office365Response(string code, string session_state)
    {
        string url = "http://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";
        code = "{Code}";
        string postData = "client_id" + "=" + "{ClientId}";
        postData += "&" + "redirect_uri" + "=" + "https://localhost:44300/Office365/Office365Response";
        postData += "&" + "client_secret" + "=" + "{ClientSecret}";
        postData += "&" + "code" + "=" + code;
        postData += "&" + "grant_type=authorization_code";
        postData += "&" + "resource" + "=" + "https://api.office.com/discovery/";

        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.

        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
}
```